# Solana: Check if deposit is finalized?

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

How can we check if a deposit is finalized using solana/web3.js? I've tried using `getTransaction` with commitment parameter `finalized` and I did get a response with slot number. However, it took a few more seconds for Solana Explorer to show status `Finalized`. This probably means receiving slot number in a response to `getTransaction` doesn't necessarily mean a deposit is finalized?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using 'confirmed' instead?

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html#Finality

Comment: I thought `finalized` was the final status?  https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#configuring-state-commitment

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Connection.confirmTransaction` with the `finalized` commitment to check that a transaction has landed. For example:

```
const signature = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction, signers);
const status = await connection.confirmTransaction(
            {
              signature: signature,
              blockhash: transaction.recentBlockhash,
              lastValidBlockHeight: transaction.lastValidBlockHeight,
            },
          )
        ).value;
if (status.err) {
  throw new Error(
    `Transaction ${signature} failed (${JSON.stringify(status)})`,
  );
}
```

This was lifted from https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/web3.js/src/util/send-and-confirm-transaction.ts